# What am I doing wrong - trying to multiply an int and a double

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to multiply the units by the price, but I cannot seem to do it. Here is the code:

```
import java.math.*;

public class FrameArray
{

    private String frameInventory;
    private int[] units;
    private double[] price;

    public FrameArray( String frame, int[] unitsArray, double[] priceArray, double value )
    {
        frameInventory = frame;
        units = unitsArray;
        price = priceArray;
    }

    public void setFrameInventory( String frame )
    {
        frameInventory = frame;
    }

    public String getFrameInventory()
    {
        return frameInventory;
    }

    public double totalValue(double value)
    {
        value = totalValue(value);
        value = units * price;
    }

    public void displayMessage()
    {
        System.out.printf( "Current frame inventory\n\n");
    }

    public void processInventory()
    {
        outputInventory();
    }

    public void outputInventory()
    {
        System.out.println( "Inventory levels:\n");
        System.out.printf( "Style     Qty    Price\n\n");

        for (int frame = 0; frame < price.length; frame++) 
            System.out.printf( "Frame %2d: %3d    %5.2f\n", frame + 1, units[ frame ], price[ frame], totalValue(frame) );
    }
}
```

I am having the problem with the units * price portion. What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: What is the problem you're referring to?

Comment: you're not returning a value. public double totalValue(double value) needs a return statement.

Comment: You cannot multiply 2 arrays in java so easily..

Comment: What do I need to do to be able to multiply the arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Your function is stuck in an endless loop!

```
public double totalValue(double value)
{
    value = totalValue(value); // Calls your function again and again
    value = units * price;

}
```

You would likely want to do something like this :

```
public double totalValue()
{
    return units * price;
}
```

However `units` and `price` need to be of type `double` or any other suitable type. In your code it are arrays. Also your argument `value` seems a bit weird to me in a `totalValue` function. Isn't that what it has to return (the total price) ?

EDIT : `units` and `price` are arrays of `double`, which means these arrays contain elements of type `double`. Hence I presume that what you want to do is something like, `return units[correspondingIndex] * price[correspondingIndex];`, hence multiplying `double`'s.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: i originally had what you put, but i kept getting an error trying to multiply the units and price

Comment: @MichaelCoca I edited my answer in order to answer your question.